# How to apply canvg() function for particular div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg, canvg

I am using `canvg()` function to convert `svg` into `canvas`.
If we use `canvg()` directly on onload it will convert all `svg` to `canvas`.
I wanted to convert `svg` related to particular `div`.

**Html**

```
<div id="notapply">
<svg><text x="50" y="50">Not to Apply!</text></svg>
</div>

<div id="apply">
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
canvg();
```

Here it should convert `svg` related to `div` which is having `id=apply`.

[Fiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/L3hondLn/130/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found an answer on your question in the source code of canvg itself: [canvg](https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg/blob/master/canvg.js)

You need to change query selector to select SVG from your div:

```
// Your selector here
var svgTags = document.querySelectorAll('#apply svg');

// Process SVG tags
for (var i=0; i<svgTags.length; i++) {
    var svgTag = svgTags[i];
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    c.width = svgTag.clientWidth;
    c.height = svgTag.clientHeight;
    svgTag.parentNode.insertBefore(c, svgTag);
    svgTag.parentNode.removeChild(svgTag);
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(svgTag);
    canvg(c, div.innerHTML);
}
```

Here is your example modified: http://jsfiddle.net/ischenkodv/L3hondLn/135/

Answer (score 4):

You can use XMLSerializer to serialize the SVG you want to send to canvg.

Something like this perhaps...

```js
canvg("canvas", (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(document.getElementById("apply").firstElementChild));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvg/1.5/canvg.min.js"></script>
<div id="notapply">
<svg><text x="50" y="50">Not to Apply!</text></svg>
 
   
</div>

<div id="apply">
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What if we have multiple svg in that div. This will not work . http://jsfiddle.net/L3hondLn/123/

Comment: Serialize them in a loop

Comment: @GennadyDogaev thanks for your response but it is not converting svg to canvas.